Rustgpu how can you index into an array of textures?
I am trying to index into a texture array in rustgpu, I have the following shader code:
#![cfg_attr(target_arch = "spirv", no_std, feature(lang_items))]
#![allow(internal_features)]

extern crate bytemuck;
extern crate spirv_std;

pub use spirv_std::glam::*;
use spirv_std::image::*;
use spirv_std::num_traits::Float;
use spirv_std::spirv;

type Texture2D = Image!(2D, type=f32, sampled);

// Fragment shader
#[spirv(fragment)]
pub fn main_fs(
    in_normal: Vec3,
    in_uv: Vec3,
    in_position: Vec3,
    in_camera_position: Vec3,
    #[spirv(descriptor_set = 1, binding = 1)] image: &[SampledImage<Texture2D>; 69],
    output: &mut Vec4,
)
{
    let index = in_uv.z.round() as usize;
    let albedo = image[index].sample(in_uv.xy());

    *output = albedo;
}

// Vertex shader
pub struct CamUBO
{
    model: Mat4,
    view: Mat4,
    proj: Mat4,
}

#[spirv(vertex)]
pub fn main_vs(
    in_position: Vec3,
    in_normal: Vec3,
    in_uv: Vec3,
    #[spirv(uniform, descriptor_set = 1, binding = 0)] camera_ubo: &CamUBO,

    #[spirv(position, invariant)] screen_pos: &mut Vec4,
    out_normal: &mut Vec3,
    out_uv: &mut Vec3,
    out_position: &mut Vec3,
    out_camera_position: &mut Vec3,
)
{
    *screen_pos = camera_ubo.proj
        * camera_ubo.view
        * camera_ubo.model
        * Vec4::new(in_position.x, in_position.y, in_position.z, 1.0);

    *out_position = screen_pos.xyz();
    *out_normal = (camera_ubo.model * in_normal.extend(0.0)).xyz();
    *out_uv = in_uv;
    *out_camera_position = -camera_ubo.view.col(3).xyz();
}


This fails to compile with the following error:
error: function pointer types are not allowed
   --> /home/makogan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-01-08-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/ptr/metadata.rs:94:1
    |
94  | pub const fn metadata<T: ?Sized>(ptr: *const T) -> <T as Pointee>::Metadata {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: used by `fmt::rt::Argument<'_>`
note: used from within `core::panicking::panic_bounds_check`
   --> /home/makogan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-01-08-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/panicking.rs:208:5
    |
208 |     panic!("index out of bounds: the len is {len} but the index is {index}")
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: called by `mesh_shader::main_fs`
   --> src/lib.rs:34:18
    |
34  |     let albedo = image[index].sample(in_uv.xy());
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: called by `main_fs`
   --> src/lib.rs:24:8
    |
24  | pub fn main_fs(
    |        ^^^^^^^

error: cannot offset a pointer to an arbitrary element
   --> /home/makogan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-01-08-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/panicking.rs:208:5
    |
208 |     panic!("index out of bounds: the len is {len} but the index is {index}")
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
note: used from within `core::panicking::panic_bounds_check`
   --> /home/makogan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-01-08-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/panicking.rs:208:5
    |
208 |     panic!("index out of bounds: the len is {len} but the index is {index}")
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: called by `mesh_shader::main_fs`
   --> src/lib.rs:34:18
    |
34  |     let albedo = image[index].sample(in_uv.xy());
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: called by `main_fs`
   --> src/lib.rs:24:8
    |
24  | pub fn main_fs(
    |        ^^^^^^^

error: `u8` without `OpCapability Int8`
   --> /home/makogan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-01-08-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/ptr/mod.rs:507:1
    |
507 | pub unsafe fn drop_in_place<T: ?Sized>(to_drop: *mut T) {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: used by unnamed global (%68396)
note: used from within `core::panicking::panic_bounds_check`
   --> /home/makogan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-01-08-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/panicking.rs:208:5
    |
208 |     panic!("index out of bounds: the len is {len} but the index is {index}")
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: called by `mesh_shader::main_fs`
   --> src/lib.rs:34:18
    |
34  |     let albedo = image[index].sample(in_uv.xy());
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: called by `main_fs`
   --> src/lib.rs:24:8
    |
24  | pub fn main_fs(
    |        ^^^^^^^

error: cannot cast between pointer types
       from `*struct fmt::rt::Argument<'_> { value: *struct fmt::rt::Opaque {  }, formatter: *fn(*struct fmt::rt::Opaque {  }, *struct fmt::Formatter<'_> { width: struct option::Option<usize> { u32, u32 }, precision: struct option::Option<usize> { u32, u32 }, fill: u32, buf: struct &mut dyn fmt::Write { *struct dyn fmt::Write {  }, *[u32; 3] }, flags: u32, align: u8 }) -> bool }`
         to `*u8`
   --> /home/makogan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-01-08-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/panicking.rs:208:5
    |
208 |     panic!("index out of bounds: the len is {len} but the index is {index}")
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
note: used from within `core::panicking::panic_bounds_check`
   --> /home/makogan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-01-08-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/panicking.rs:208:5
    |
208 |     panic!("index out of bounds: the len is {len} but the index is {index}")
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: called by `mesh_shader::main_fs`
   --> src/lib.rs:34:18
    |
34  |     let albedo = image[index].sample(in_uv.xy());
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: called by `main_fs`
   --> src/lib.rs:24:8
    |
24  | pub fn main_fs(
    |        ^^^^^^^

error: cannot cast between pointer types
       from `*u8`
         to `**fn(*struct fmt::rt::Opaque {  }, *struct fmt::Formatter<'_> { width: struct option::Option<usize> { u32, u32 }, precision: struct option::Option<usize> { u32, u32 }, fill: u32, buf: struct &mut dyn fmt::Write { *struct dyn fmt::Write {  }, *[u32; 3] }, flags: u32, align: u8 }) -> bool`
   --> /home/makogan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-01-08-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/panicking.rs:208:5
    |
208 |     panic!("index out of bounds: the len is {len} but the index is {index}")
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
note: used from within `core::panicking::panic_bounds_check`
   --> /home/makogan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-01-08-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/panicking.rs:208:5
    |
208 |     panic!("index out of bounds: the len is {len} but the index is {index}")
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: called by `mesh_shader::main_fs`
   --> src/lib.rs:34:18
    |
34  |     let albedo = image[index].sample(in_uv.xy());
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: called by `main_fs`
   --> src/lib.rs:24:8
    |
24  | pub fn main_fs(
    |        ^^^^^^^

error: const_bitcast
    |
note: used from within `core::panicking::panic_bounds_check`
   --> /home/makogan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-01-08-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/panicking.rs:208:5
    |
208 |     panic!("index out of bounds: the len is {len} but the index is {index}")
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: called by `mesh_shader::main_fs`
   --> src/lib.rs:34:18
    |
34  |     let albedo = image[index].sample(in_uv.xy());
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: called by `main_fs`
   --> src/lib.rs:24:8
    |
24  | pub fn main_fs(
    |        ^^^^^^^

error: cannot cast between pointer types
       from `*[struct fmt::rt::Argument<'_> { value: *struct fmt::rt::Opaque {  }, formatter: *fn(*struct fmt::rt::Opaque {  }, *struct fmt::Formatter<'_> { width: struct option::Option<usize> { u32, u32 }, precision: struct option::Option<usize> { u32, u32 }, fill: u32, buf: struct &mut dyn fmt::Write { *struct dyn fmt::Write {  }, *[u32; 3] }, flags: u32, align: u8 }) -> bool }; 2]`
         to `*[struct fmt::rt::Argument<'_> { value: *struct fmt::rt::Opaque {  }, formatter: *fn(*struct fmt::rt::Opaque {  }, *struct fmt::Formatter<'_> { width: struct option::Option<usize> { u32, u32 }, precision: struct option::Option<usize> { u32, u32 }, fill: u32, buf: struct &mut dyn fmt::Write { *struct dyn fmt::Write {  }, *[u32; 3] }, flags: u32, align: u8 }) -> bool }]`
   --> /home/makogan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-01-08-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/panicking.rs:208:5
    |
208 |     panic!("index out of bounds: the len is {len} but the index is {index}")
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
note: used from within `core::panicking::panic_bounds_check`
   --> /home/makogan/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-2024-01-08-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/panicking.rs:208:5
    |
208 |     panic!("index out of bounds: the len is {len} but the index is {index}")
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: called by `mesh_shader::main_fs`
   --> src/lib.rs:34:18
    |
34  |     let albedo = image[index].sample(in_uv.xy());
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: called by `main_fs`
   --> src/lib.rs:24:8
    |
24  | pub fn main_fs(
    |        ^^^^^^^

warning: `mesh-shader` (lib) generated 3 warnings
error: could not compile `mesh-shader` (lib) due to 7 previous errors; 3 warnings emitted
thread 'main' panicked at crates/vulkan_bindings/src/shader_parsing/rust_gpu_parsing.rs:44:14:
called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: BuildFailed
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/75c68cfd2b9870f2953b62d250bd7d0564a7b56d/library/std/src/panicking.rs:645:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/75c68cfd2b9870f2953b62d250bd7d0564a7b56d/library/core/src/panicking.rs:72:14
   2: core::result::unwrap_failed
             at /rustc/75c68cfd2b9870f2953b62d250bd7d0564a7b56d/library/core/src/result.rs:1649:5
   3: vulkan_bindings::shader_parsing::rust_gpu_parsing::parse_shader
   4: vulkan_bindings::shader_program::ShaderProgram::new
   5: <vulkan_bindings::RenderContext as ne_core::gpu_api::GpuApi>::add_shader_from_memory
   6: <vulkan_bindings::RenderContext as ne_core::gpu_api::GpuApi>::add_shader
   7: _02_mesh::main
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.

The most relevant bit is likely error: cannot offset a pointer to an arbitrary element. This seems to be the source of the problem, because when I index the texture array through a constant I do manage to compile.
However, this code is a translation of some hlsl code I had:
[[vk::binding(1, 1)]]
Texture2D<float4> textures[69];
[[vk::binding(2, 1)]]
SamplerState textures_sampler[69];

#include <linalg.hlsl>

vec4 Lambert(
    vec3 position,
    vec3 normal,
    vec3 albedo,
    vec3 light_position,
    vec3 light_color)
{
    vec4 color = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);
    vec3 l = normalize(light_position - position);

    vec3 n = normalize(normal);

    float intensity = length(light_color);
    light_color = normalize(light_color);
    color = vec4(
        dot(l, n) * albedo * light_color,
        1);

    return color;
}

float4 main(
    [[vk::location(0)]] float3 normal : NORMAL0,
    [[vk::location(1)]] float3 uv : UV0,
    [[vk::location(2)]] float3 position : POSITION0,
    [[vk::location(3)]] float3 camera_position : CAMPOS0
) : SV_TARGET
{
    uint index = int(round(uv.z));
    float4 albedo = textures[index].Sample(textures_sampler[index], uv.xy);

    return (Lambert(
        position,
        normal,
        albedo.xyz,
        vec3(5, 1000, 5),
        normalize(vec3(1, 1, 1))) * 2.0 + 0.1);
}

So in principle it should be possible to generate the appropriate spirv to index into an array of textures.
I was hoping someone could give me a hand

I have no experience with spirv_std, but with a quick peek I found that SampledImage has "const ARRAYED: u32" generic parameter, which might suggest that you shouldn't use a slice &[SampledImage; N], but rather a properly created texture array SampledImage and use sample() on it. But again I have no idea what I'm talking about

I could create texture arrays instead of arrays of textures, but then all of my images will need to have the same dimensions. Which is an issue as my current data does not obey that property, hence why I was using an array of textures instead.

Easiest
Apparently the only thing that is needed is to use a special trait in spirv_std toindex into the array without checking the bounds:
#[spirv(fragment)]
pub fn main_fs(
    in_normal: Vec3,
    in_uv: Vec3,
    in_position: Vec3,
    in_camera_position: Vec3,
    #[spirv(descriptor_set = 1, binding = 1)] image: &[SampledImage<Texture2D>; 69],
   &RuntimeArray<SampledTexture2D>,
    output: &mut Vec4,
)
{
    let index = in_uv.z.round() as usize;
    let albedo = unsafe { image.index_unchecked(index).sample(in_uv.xy()) };

    *output = albedo;
}

Old answer
The solution seems to be as follows. First raw arrays are not sutiable for shaders, one must use a special type like this:
#[spirv(fragment)]
pub fn main_fs(
    in_normal: Vec3,
    in_uv: Vec3,
    in_position: Vec3,
    in_camera_position: Vec3,
    #[spirv(descriptor_set = 1, binding = 1)] image: &RuntimeArray<SampledTexture2D>, // this is a slice, almost
    output: &mut Vec4,
)

Then when compiling using spirv builder one needs the following arguments:
        SpirvBuilder::new(path, "spirv-unknown-vulkan1.2")
            .print_metadata(MetadataPrintout::DependencyOnly)
            .preserve_bindings(true)
            .spirv_metadata(SpirvMetadata::NameVariables)
            .scalar_block_layout(true)
            .multimodule(true)
            .capability(Capability::SampledImageArrayDynamicIndexing) // Don't know if we need it
            .capability(Capability::RuntimeDescriptorArray) // Definitely need it
            .extension("SPV_EXT_descriptor_indexing") // Probably need it
            .extra_arg("target-feature=+RuntimeDescriptorArray,") // Might need it
            .build()
            .unwrap()

